# How to launch a new Internet Explorer process using javascript (iexplore.exe)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events

Is it possible to launch new IE process each time when we open new window through Javascript?

Comment: Have your tried window.open(...) ?

Comment: Where does this JavaScript run?  In an IE browser?  Firefox?  Node.js?  Windows Scripting Host?  Some custom process hosting V8?

Comment: Javascript will run in IE only... As per msdn blog... it has some algorithms which decides when to start new ie.exe... but we want always to start new ie.exe http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/09/opening-a-new-tab-may-launch-a-new-process-with-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to do from a in-browser JS, without installing additional stuff on the clients machine!

I mean, for real. Do you **really** want a website to be able to control the process management of your browser? Think about the performance and security risks! Believe me, you really don't want this!

If you are just in-browser JS, you are just a website. If one website could do this, every website could do this! So its not possible, and thats for a reason!

It would be interesting **why** u actually wanna do that! I general it's a bad idea to hack around default process management of a application, written by people who know more then you. (like the IE)

If you really wanna do that, and you can run code on another way on the clients, for example by installing software, you some possibilities.

- For example, you could use a IE addin, call that addin from JS and let this adding open a new IE process with the new website.
- Or you create run a local deamon service, who is opening a HTTP listener on a certain port on localhost. Then every website can call that deamon via AJAX and let it open a new IE with a specific website. **Be careful** with that! Make sure that only a new IE can be opened, and share a secret key between your website and that deamon, so that only websites who know that secret key can open a new Process!

In every way, remind that its very easy to make mistakes on the implementation who can leak  **massive security issues**! Always think twice about what you make, and be prepared to fix a bug immediately.